# Cannot access CartoDB with OGR

Tags: gdal, carto, ogr2ogr

I'm having issues using OGR to interact with tables on my CartoDB account.  Initially I was trying to upload data using ogr2ogr:

```
ogr2ogr --config CARTODB_API_KEY abcdefghi -t_srs EPSG:4326 -f CartoDB "CartoDB:thementat" agg.json
```

This error out, suggesting that I was attempting to create a database... something the CartoDB driver doesn't support:

```
ERROR 1: HTTP error code : 404
ERROR 1: HTML error page returned by server
ERROR 1: CartoDB driver doesn't support database creation.
ERROR 1: CartoDB driver failed to create CartoDB:thementat
```

Research had indicated that that I probably shouldn't trust this  so I tried to simplify using ogrinfo:

```
ogrinfo -ro "CartoDB:thementat tables=parcel"
```

This returned the following error:

```
ERROR 1: HTTP error code : 404
ERROR 1: HTML error page returned by server
FAILURE:
Unable to open datasource `CartoDB:thementat tables=parcel' with the following drivers.
  -> PCIDSK
  -> netCDF
  -> PDF
  -> ESRI Shapefile
  -> MapInfo File
  -> UK .NTF
  -> OGR_SDTS
  -> S57
  -> DGN
  -> OGR_VRT
  -> REC
  -> Memory
  -> BNA
  -> CSV
  -> NAS
  -> GML
  -> GPX
  -> KML
  -> GeoJSON
  -> Interlis 1
  -> Interlis 2
  -> OGR_GMT
  -> GPKG
  -> SQLite
  -> WAsP
  -> PostgreSQL
  -> OpenFileGDB
  -> XPlane
  -> DXF
  -> Geoconcept
  -> GeoRSS
  -> GPSTrackMaker
  -> VFK
  -> PGDUMP
  -> OSM
  -> GPSBabel
  -> SUA
  -> OpenAir
  -> OGR_PDS
  -> WFS
  -> HTF
  -> AeronavFAA
  -> EDIGEO
  -> GFT
  -> SVG
  -> CouchDB
  -> Cloudant
  -> Idrisi
  -> ARCGEN
  -> SEGUKOOA
  -> SEGY
  -> ODS
  -> XLSX
  -> ElasticSearch
  -> CartoDB
  -> AmigoCloud
  -> SXF
  -> Selafin
  -> JML
  -> PLSCENES
  -> CSW
  -> VDV
  -> TIGER
  -> AVCBin
  -> AVCE00
  -> HTTP
```

I suspect it isn't connecting to my CartoDB account, because this works:

```
ogrinfo -ro "Carto:gdalautotest2 tables=tm_world_borders_simpl_0_3"
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Welcome to gis.stackexchange! Please edit the title of your question to include enough information for future visitors to be able to find this thread when looking for the same problem.

Comment: What version of GDAL do you have (ogr2ogr --version)?